# Get script content with regular expression pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract the content of a certain script from a website.

Therefore I'm using the **re.search()** function with my regular expression pattern.

This is the start of the script which content I want to extract:

```
<script>
new WH.Wow.TodayInWow(WH.ge('today-in-wow'), [{"id":"dungeons-and-raids",
...
```

And this is my Python 3.11. code:

```
import re
import json
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

import mysql.connector
from time import sleep


req = Request(
    "https://www.wowhead.com/de/", headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
)
html_page = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")

sleep(5)

json_data = re.search(
    r"TodayInWow\(WH\.ge\('today-in-wow'\), (.*), true\);", html_page
)
json_data = json.loads(json_data.group(1))

print(json_data)
```

This gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Is there any error in my regular expression or why can't it find the specific content?

Comment: I don't see the string `', true'` anywhere in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at [WebScraping using BeautifulSoup](https://www.edureka.co/blog/web-scraping-with-python/)
then you could get the whole script as a string by searching for the script tags.

This approach completely avoids the need for regex:

```py
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

req = Request("https://www.wowhead.com/de/", 
              headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
html_page = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
scripts = soup.find_all("script")

for script in scripts:
    print(script.get_text(), '\n')
```